# Why does Object.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() direct to src/main/resources?

Tags: java, operating-system

I wrote a class in `src/main/java/com/xxx/service/impl`, and loaded a properties file by using `class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`. The method looked up the file in `src/main/resources` but not in src or the project directory, why? What's the difference between folder and package?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java/1464366#1464366

Answer (score 1):

getResourceAsStream() looks into the classpath that was provided to the program at runtime. Classpath is a collection of "places" where the program is allowed to look for its constituents, like classes or resource files.

A package is just a folder that happens to be in your application's classpath.